# Active Admin - Can I add a Data Attribute to the Form Tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I need to add a data attribute to a form tag created by Active Admin.

Here is the current Active Admin form code ...

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Pdf do
      menu parent: "Video Series"
      PDFTYPES = {
        outline: "Outline",
        transcript: "Transcript"
      }

      member_action :getvideos do
        unless params[:id].blank?
         render :json => Video.where(video_series_id: params[:id]).to_json.html_safe
        end
      end

      member_action :clearvideo do
        #binding.pry
        #puts "pdfID : #{id}"
      end

      index do
        column :title
        column :description
        column :pdf_type
        column :created_at
        column :updated_at
        actions
      end

      form do |f|
        f.inputs "Pdf Content" do
          f.input :title
          f.input :url
          f.input :description
          f.input :pos
          f.input :video_series, as: :select, include_blank: true, collection: VideoSeries.all.map { |video| ["#{video.title}", video.id] } 
          f.input :pdf_type, as: :select, include_blank: true, collection: PDFTYPES.sort.map {|key,val| [val,key]}, input_html: { data: {pdf_id: pdf.id} }
          f.input :video, as: :select, include_blank: true, collection: Video.where(video_series_id: f.object.video_series_id).map { |video| ["#{video.title}", video.id] }
          f.actions
        end
      end
    end
```

You can see in my code above how I create a data attribute on the second select input named "*pdf_type*" -  "***input_html: { data: {pdf_id: pdf.id} }***."

I would like this data attribute on the form tag. Can this be done with Active Admin?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this that way

```
form html: { data: { attribute: 'value' } } do |f|
  # Your code goes there
  ...
end
```